# AspNetCore 3.0 Could not load type on Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis

I'm trying to publish and run a C#/.NET project using IIS but whenever I publish, I'm getting the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

The Application logs in Event Viewer show:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.6603
.NET Core Version: 3.0.3
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization, Version=3.0.3.0,
```

I've tried upgrading/downgrading NuGet packages, manually deleting contents from the IIS directory and republishing, and restarting IIS. All the Nuget packages seem to be using a compatible version and the server should have all the proper SDKs installed as we've run .NET core 3.0 projects on it before.

Everything seems to compile and run fine locally, it only breaks when published and hosted via IIS.

Please let me know your ideas

Thanks!

Comment: .NET Core 3.0 is end-of-life. Once you upgrade to a supported version and face the same issue, run some diagnostics and paste the report here, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: I guess this may related with your server's asp.net core runtime version, I suggest you could try to publish the application with self-contained and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this documentation https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8980 and https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/. I follow the instructions and it solve my issue above.